# Google cloud Vision and Clarifai doesn't Support tagging for 360 degree images and videos

Tags: image, image-processing, google-cloud-vision, object-detection-api, clarifai

I'm working on image processing. So far Google Cloud Vision and Clarifai are the best API's to detect objects from images and videos, but both API's doesn't support object detection from 360 degree images and videos. Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: what do you mean with doesn't support it? all 360° images I've encountered so far were regular jpegs or bitmaps.

Comment: when I provide url link of 360 degree image at clarifai demo it gives an error that states invalid image or video url.  You can try this url : https://kuula.co/share/7lXF1?fs=1&vr=0&thumbs=1&chromeless=0&logo=0 at https://www.clarifai.com/demo

Comment: Not sure what you expect to happen. The site says "Give us a direct link to a file on the web". The link you provided is no such link. It points to a webbased 360 image viewer, not to a file...